# "Table not mapped" with NHibernate + Active Record

Tags: .net, nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I'm using Active Record with ActiveRecord Facility, and am trying to use a custom NHibernate query. Do I need to define a mapping for a class even though it extends ActiveRecordBase and has ActiveRecord attribute?

```
[ActiveRecord("VotesOnQuestions")]
public class VoteOnQuestion : ActiveRecordBase<VoteOnQuestion>
{
    [CompositeKey]
    public VoteKey Key { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public VoteType Vote { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to create the following query:

```
session.CreateQuery("SELECT vote, COUNT(*) FROM votesonquestions" +
                    " WHERE questionid = :questionId GROUP BY vote");
```

But I'm getting this exception:

> "votesonquestions is not mapped"

Comment: do you have a "votesonquestions" class? you need one.

Comment: I have one, edited my answer to include it.

Comment: The class is named **VoteOnQuestion**, the query says ** votesonquestions** (note case and extra *s*).

Comment: But I configured ActiveRecord's pluralizeTableNames, that should have done it, no? Other operations through the VoteOnQuestion class works perfectly.

Comment: In the query you can only refer mapped classes (which are case-sensitive), not tables.

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what you really meant - I tried to add a separate Map of VoteOnQuestion, for some reason. Then it hit me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as the exception says, you need a class marked with `[ActiveRecord]` that maps the **votesonquestions** (I'm guessing it's called like that) table.

Inheriting from `ActiveRecordBase` is optional.

In the query you can only refer mapped classes (which are case-sensitive), not tables. So in this case, the query should be:

```
session.CreateQuery("SELECT vote, COUNT(*) FROM VoteOnQuestion" +
                    " WHERE questionid = :questionId GROUP BY vote");
```